# How many rhymes are possible in a 10 lines poem?

Tags: combinatorics-on-words

When 2 lines in a poem ends with the same (or similiar) sound we have a rhyme. When studying poetry at highschool **we were taught that there exists only 4 rhyme types, however I suspect they are much more!**

We choose to encode rhymes as single characters so the following poem:

> My wagon sinking under grass so tall
>
> The flowery petals in foam on me fall

has a A-A rhyme.

---

- 2 lines should not be more far from each other than another 2 lines because otherwise we cannot "hear" the rhyme.
- So we can view a 10 lines poem like a sequence of 10 characters, where each character has no more than any other 2 characters before a identical one occurs

In example a valid sequence is:

> ABACBCDBDB

But a **not** valid sequence is:

> AAABBBBBB **A**

Because the last "A" is not "rhymed" with anything (no nearby A).

Some other valid sequences

> AAAAAAAAAA
>
> AABBCCDDEE
>
> ABBABBBBBB

Since we have 10 lines, **we cannot have more than 5 characters**, so how many rhymes are really possible in 10 lines?

Comment: Incidentally, what you're calling a rhyme is usually called a rhyme *scheme*, isn't it?  For instance, two common sonnet rhyme schemes are the Shakespearean and the Petrarchan (named after their famous exponents).  Shakespearean is usually ababcdcdefefgg, and Petrarchan is usually abbaabbacdecde or something like that, but there are variations just for those two, so I'm not sure why it might be said that there are only four basic rhyme schemes.  Perhaps that was just for quatrains, where we might (conceivably) limit ourselves to aabb, abab, abba, and aaaa?

Comment: yes I mean rhyme schemes. I really dont know why school teached 4 schemes, maybe over -simplification?

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider this by solving the more general question of how many rhyme schemes are possible for an $n$ line poem. To do this, we note the following rule:

> To construct a $n+1$ line poem from an $n$ line poem, append either a new rhyme or an existing rhyme that appears in the last $3$ lines of the poem.

So, for instance the poem $ABBABB$ can be extended by adding an $A$ or $B$ or $C$, since $A$ and $B$ have already appeared. In particular, we may characterize . For instance, if the poem terminates in $XXX$ where $X$ is some rhyme, we may either append $X$ to it, or some new rhyme $Y$. We will denote this relation by saying
$$XXX\rightarrow XXX\text{ or }XXY$$
since a suffix of $XXX$ may be transformed to either $XXX$ or $XXY$ by appending a character. We will note that when using variables, we have $XXY\cong YYX$ since each defines the same partition, just with the variable characters $X$ and $Y$ switched. We can write out all of the evolution rules as follows:
$$XXX\rightarrow XXX \text{ or }XXY$$
$$XXY\rightarrow XYX \text{ or }XYY\text{ or }XYZ$$
$$XYX\rightarrow YXX\cong XYY \text{ or }YXY\cong XYX\text{ or }YXZ\cong XYZ$$
$$XYY\rightarrow YYX\cong XXY \text{ or }YYY\cong XXX\text{ or }YYZ\cong XXY$$
$$XYZ\rightarrow YZX\cong XYZ\text{ or }YZY\cong XYX \text{ or }YZZ\cong XYY \text{ or }YZW\cong XYZ.$$
Note that knowing which of the rules we use at each step suffices to characterize the poem. For instance, the end of the string $ABBABB$ is of the form $XYY$. If we apply the rule $XYY\rightarrow YYZ$ we get $ABBABBC$. Then, since $YYZ\cong XXY$, the end of the string is still of the form $XXY$. If we then applied the rule $XXY\rightarrow XYX$, we would get $ABBABBCB$. We may see that this will always be well-defined, since every character $X,\,Y,\,Z,\,W$ has a specific assigned rhyme based on the suffix or is assigned to a new rhyme.

We can collect the information on the transitions by considering that all the possible suffixes are of the forms $$XXX,\,XXY,\,XYX,\,XYY,\,XYZ.$$
We can write how many transitions from each of these suffixes to each other suffix and collect this in a matrix:
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2  \end{bmatrix}$$
For instance, the $2$ in the fourth row of the second column indicates that there are two transitions from a suffix of the fourth form $XYY$ to a suffix of the second form $XXY$ (in particular, the transformations to $YYX$ or $YYZ$ do this). Now, let $V$ be the vector $(1,1,1,1,1)$. We can show that the product
$$VM^{k}$$
is a vector whose components list how many $3+k$ line poems have a suffix of each of the given forms. For instance for $k=0$, the vector $(1,1,1,1,1)$ tells us that there is one three line poem with each suffix. For $k=1$ we get the vector $(2,3,3,3,4)$ meaning that there are two four line poems ending with $XXX$ and four ending with $XYZ$ and $3$ ending with every other suffix. For $k=7$ we get the vector $(1545, 2609, 3420, 3420, 4964)$ and the sum of the entries is $15958$, meaning there are $15958$ rhyme patterns for ten line poems.

Comment: It's occurred to me that this counts $ABCDEFGHIJ$ as a valid poem - that is, a poem with no rhymes. If you require that every line rhymes with another line, I could modify the method slightly to make that work. (Though it requires $8$ times as many states - but being clever, you can reduce the current matrix to $3$ states, so we'd get $24$ states total, which isn't too bad).